# FirefoxWebdriver on remote machines

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver, selenium-grid2

Is it required to install the Firefox web driver on the remote machines acting as node or hub?
I tested the hub and nodes locally? I think, it is necessary to install the web driver on the hub and node. Any comments or suggestions?

Update:

Selenium jars are running (i.e. Java is installed and web driver also exists within the selenium jar as per the documentation). Why am I getting this error

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to connect to    
host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
```

Also,

```
(process:13023): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for **no display specified** have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/523677/error-cannot-open-display-0-0-while-starting-remotelly-firefox) and for port issue can u check whether any instance of firefox is running on your node at that port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, I was able to find the root cause, I was running these on the headless machines and needed those to be configured in order to launch ff. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything on the machine that runs the hub except the selenium jar.

On the machine that runs the node you only need **firefox itself** to be installed, and the selenium jar running.
Firefox doesn't need a webdriver, only chrome.

from [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver)

> Firefox driver is included in the selenium-server-stanalone.jar